# How to stretch the container in bootstrap to fit the whole page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i know the boostrap container has a set width to it etc and i want to try and change it so that it fits the whole screen, So i am trying to achieve this effect here:

[image]

So i want to have half the row with a picture and the other half with the text , but eevry time i play around with the container it screws up , and when i try and see if its responsive, the text and image overlap each other and i was wondering if there is a way to fix this

**Im using bootstrap 3**

So far i have :

HTML:

```
            <div class="clientsParrlex">
        <div class="container newconwidth">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <img src="images/9.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
           <h1><span class="one">Våra</span> <span class="two">Klienter</span></h1>
        <p><strong>Quisque dolor lacus, commodo id hendrerit viverra, euismod in odio.</strong></p>
        <p>Aliquam fermentum massa ac est sollicitudin, at ultricies ligula tristique. Cras finibus, nulla ac convallis feugiat, nisl nisl lobortis est, eget auctor velit magna vel nunc. Donec nec eros rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Aenean nisi neque, aliquam ut nibh sit amet, finibus sagittis tortor aenean consectetur.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clientsParrlex {
    background-color: #0f0e0e;
        padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Thank you again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?
I added a class called "level" with row to apply a padding on the div columns and then changed the width of image to 100% of the column.

```css
.clientsParrlex {
  background-color: #0f0e0e;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.level > div{
padding:10px;
}

.level > div > img{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="clientsParrlex">
  <div class="container newconwidth">
    <div class="row level">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/650x300">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <h1><span class="one">Våra</span> <span class="two">Klienter</span></h1>
        <p><strong>Quisque dolor lacus, commodo id hendrerit viverra, euismod in odio.</strong></p>
        <p>Aliquam fermentum massa ac est sollicitudin, at ultricies ligula tristique. Cras finibus, nulla ac convallis feugiat, nisl nisl lobortis est, eget auctor velit magna vel nunc. Donec nec eros rhoncus.</p>
        <p>Aenean nisi neque, aliquam ut nibh sit amet, finibus sagittis tortor aenean consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change "container" to "container-fluid"

```html
<div class="container newconwidth"> --->  <div class="container-fluid newconwidth">
```

Class "container" has default styling (I think "max-width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;") and this is problem, because with the property "max-width" your container doesn't take 100% of the window width.

In "container-fluid" class there is no property "max-width", so your container takes up 100% of the window width.

Answer (score 0):

you can put an id to the container you want to be full screen and set its margins and paddings to 0